# Jquery script on mobile device

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

So my script works fine on desktops but it looks like when I open the links on mobile devices it loads the script behind the page so I can't see it. Is there a way to have the script popup in front like on desktops?

```css
/* rates & packages section */

.packages {
  width: 20.42%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: left;
  background: #73c8ff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px #70A0BF solid;
  text-align: center;
  h2 {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  }
  .price {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  button {
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  button:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
}
.popular {
  background-color: #6AFFB7;
  color: black;
  h2 {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- some test stuff -->
<script>
 var modal = (function(){
  var 
  method = {},
  $overlay,
  $modal,
  $content,
  $close;

  // Center the modal in the viewport
  method.center = function () {
   var top, left;

   top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
   left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

   $modal.css({
    top:top + $(window).scrollTop(), 
    left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
   });
  };

  // Open the modal
  method.open = function (settings) {
   $content.empty().append(settings.content);

   $modal.css({
    width: settings.width || 'auto', 
    height: settings.height || 'auto'
   });

   method.center();
   $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.center);
   $modal.show();
   $overlay.show();
  };

  // Close the modal
  method.close = function () {
   $modal.hide();
   $overlay.hide();
   $content.empty();
   $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
  };

  // Generate the HTML and add it to the document
  $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
  $content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
  $close = $('<a id="close" href="#">close</a>');

  $modal.hide();
  $overlay.hide();
  $modal.append($content, $close);

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').append($overlay, $modal);      
  });

  $close.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   method.close();
  });
      
        $overlay.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   method.close();
  });

  return method;
 }());

 // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $.get('ajax.html', function(data){
   modal.open({content: data});
  });

  $('#successMap').click(function(e){
   modal.open({content: "<p>You know where you want to be.  You just don’t know how to get there.</p><P>I can help.</p><P>If you were going to a new destination for the first time, you would likely look at a map (or use GPS).  Why should your business be any different?</P><P>I will help you figure out exactly where you are at and provide you clear, actionable directions, to help get you closer to your desired destination.</P><p>The Success Map Session is perfect for you if:</p><ul><li>We’ve never worked together, and you want to work on a small 'test' project.</li><li>You know where you want your business or marketing to be, but are unsure or the best path to get there.</li><li>You have a single bio, email sequence, blog post, tagline, an opt-in offer, or some other chunk of copy written and you want me to look at it for emotional appeal and psychological impact.  </li><li>You are trying to 'do-it-yourself' and have no idea where to start. I’ll help you map it out.</li><li>You want a brainstorming partner.</li><li>You want to discuss freelancing, copywriting, behavioral economics, social psychology, writing, the latest episode of The Walking Dead or House of Cards </li><li>You want a tutoring session on how to write with emotion, how to inject psychological triggers, or how to write with personality.</li></ul><P>This is an hour-long session.</P><p>Note: This session might be a little longer (at my expense) if I deem necessary to help you.</p>"});
   e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#officeHours').click(function(e){
   modal.open({content: "<P>I work with you, 1 on 1, to elevate your marketing and copy with emotional magnetism and psychological triggers.  I use the power of human psychology to craft copy that works through the art and science of ethical persuasion.  </P><P>When you work with me, you get:</P><ul><li> “Big picture” consulting that solves business problems </li><li>An analytical and scientific approach, doing what is proven to work</li><li>Unique and tailored sales copy that meets your needs</li><li>Ownership of written content upon delivery and payment</li></ul><p>The Office Hour provides you a personal BEHAVIORAL MARKETING EXPERT to help you influence buyer behavior with your product or service.</p><p>Here are some things I can work on during a Professor Power Hour session:</p><ul><li>Your Bio or About Page</li><li>Email marketing strategy and implementation</li><li>Company Branding</li><li>Sales page, including a headline and subheadline</li><li>ANY copy that is not converting, is a jumbled mess, or that makes even your eyes glaze over</li><li>You need help creating one important, eyeball-grabbing, 'you had me at hello' piece of writing</li><li>Your tagline</li><li>Your opt-in offer</li><li>A product name</li><li>Blog post ideas that ROCK</li></ul><p>I will give you targeted word changes and suggestions to make it way more powerful, persuasive, and emotionally engaging. </p><p>I am not satisfied unless you are saying, 'You made me want to buy my product.'</p><p>NOTE: Know you’re going to want more than 1 hour? Get 3 hours for the special price of $675. That’s $75 off the normal total.</P>"});
   e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#bio').click(function(e){
   modal.open({content: "<p>To capture a lead...<p>You have to capture their attention...<p>You have less than 2.7 seconds to get the job done.<p>This is less time than it takes to take a deep breath.<p>It might sound cliché, but…<p>You don't get a second chance to make a first impression.<p>What would you do if this happened to you:<p>I met this guy at an event.  To be honest, I don't even remember his name.  He handed me a business card.  The card was frayed and worn around the edges and had a crease running down the middle, almost like it had been folded and then unfolded.  I looked at the card and noticed that coffee or some other dark liquid had spilled on it, staining it a light brown.  Then, I looked at the text.  Can you believe that there were typos?<p>TYPOS!</p>Making matters worse, the text was illegible, with grammar and spelling problems throughout.  The text just didn’t make sense.  Adding insult to injury, the card had a musty odor; the kind of odor that reminds you of a damp, musty basement or a cave…<p>Would you call this guy?</p>If he doesn’t care enough to present himself in the best possible way.  Will he care about your business or problems?<p>A good bio is not an expense.  It is an investment.<p>Get this right the first time.  The way you present your self builds rapport and trust.  More importantly, it protects and preserves your image, reputation, and brand.<p>You need emotionally powerful and engaging copy that is tailored to you, your product, and your service. </p><p>When you work with me, we will:</p><ul><li>Discuss your audience, your message, and your background and work to align them so that visitors to your Bio or About Page see you as an added value</li><li>Write an emotionally engaging bio that is not ABOUT YOU, but ABOUT THEM – your audience</li><li>Write a bio or about page that is laser focused on achieving an objective</li></ul><P>On average, ONE bio or page takes ONE day.</p><p>Got more than one page to write? Let's talk.</p>"});
   e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#relationship').click(function(e){
   modal.open({content: "<p>If you build relationships, success will follow.<p>You spent time, money, effort, and energy capturing the lead.<p>Now what?<p>You need to build and develop a long-term relationship built on trust.<p>I help you develop a strategy to build and cultivate these relationships through tailored email campaigns.<p>Whether you need a short email sequence for prospects that sign up for your list, a sales sequence to sell a product or service, or a year’s worth of emails for a campaign, I can help.<p>You know good copy is not an expense.  It is an investment.<p>You need emotionally powerful and engaging copy that is created solely for your product or service.  Copy that connects with your audience.  Copy that solves a problem they have, but don’t want or copy that gives them something they want, but don’t have.<p>Together, we will deliver.<p>We will start by discussing your audience, your message, and your product or service so that we can develop a strategy for your email campaign.  I then construct an email campaign that connects with your audience and meets the objectives.</p><p>This tailored option includes:</p><ul><li>The creation of email sequences, designed to keep your audience engaged with meaningful content</li><li>The creation of email sales sequences, designed to get your prospects to click “buy”</li><li>The creation of an entire email campaign</li><li>You are looking for a “done for you” lead generation campaigns</li></ul><P>The number of variables in this option are endless.  Contact me to discuss how I can help you build enduring, meaningful and profitable relationships with your clients or prospects."});
   e.preventDefault();
  });
  
 });
</script>

<!-- end test stuff -->

<div class="packages">
  <h2>
    Success Map Session
  </h2>
  <p class="price">
    $150
  </p>
  <p>
    You know where you want to be. I help you map out a path.
  </p>


<button id="successMap">
  Is this for me?
</button>
  
</div>

<div class="packages popular">
  <h2>
    Office Hours
  </h2>
  <p class="price">
    <BR>$250
  </p>
  <p>
    Let’s make your copy stand out, connect emotionally, sound like you, flow better, sell better.
  </p>
 
  <button id="officeHours">
  Is this for me?
  </button>
  
</div>

<div class="packages">
  <h2>
  Bio 2.0
  </h2>
  <p class="price">
   <BR>$500
  </p>
  <p>
    We will create an About Page or Bio that connects
  </p>


<button id="bio">
  Is this for me?
</button>
  
</div>

<div class="packages">
  <h2>
   E-Relationship
    
  </h2>
  <p class="price">
  <BR>on request
  </p>
  <p>
    Email campaigns that convert cold leads into hot buyers
  </p>

<button id="relationship">
 Is this for me?
</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your overlay to remain in place in the foreground, you need to add some positioning and z-index rules.

Add this CSS to your website:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { /* Set this to your preferred mobile width target */
  #modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
  }
}
```